# Windows Forms C# application - Webbrowser control not displaying custom html content when a user choose 125% or 150% for the OS font size?

Tags: html, winforms, webbrowser-control, highdpi

We had designed a Windows Form application such that it is suitable for all the resolutions. Now, we came across a situation where the custom html is not getting displayed in the WebBrowser control when we choose 125% or 150% for the font size . It is getting displayed correctly when i choose 100% as shown in screenshot below

[image]

I had set the screen resolution to 1440x900 and changed the setting to 125% as shown in screenshot below. In this case a blank page is getting displayed in WebBrowser control. I am using the following code to display the html content in the WebBrowser control

```
WebBrowser1.DocumentText =
            "<html><body>Please enter your name:<br/>" +
            "<input type='text' name='userName'/><br/>" +
            "<a href='http://www.microsoft.com'>continue</a>" +
            "</body></html>"
```

[image]

Can you please suggest on why the html content is not getting displayed when i choose 125% whereas it is getting displayed when i choose 100% and provide a solution for it?

Comment: Add the HTML5 header (`<!DOCTYPE html> <head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">...</head>`). Make your app DpiAware.

Comment: The app is made DPI Aware only. I have added the HTML5 header tag as suggested but still the blank is getting displayed in WebBrowser control

Comment: `string header = "<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\"></head>"; string html = "[Your HTML]"; webBrowser1.Navigate(""); var doc = webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true); doc.Write(header+html); webBrowser1.Refresh();"`. I don't know what *The app is made DPI Aware only* means (*only*?).

Comment: The app is made DPI Aware means we had set the following set of lines in configuration file <System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
  <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
  <add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="false" />
 </System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>  and added the app.manifest file and enabled the tag  <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

Comment: I tried the way you have suggested but still blank is getting displayed in webbrowser control when it is set to 125% where it is loading correctly when it is set to 100%

Comment: I found that the html content is getting displayed at the top when DPI Scaling is set to 125%. The WebBrowser control is not displaying the content from the middle instead of displaying it right from the top and as a result blank page is getting displayed. Can you please suggest on how to show the html from the top?